# How to make a program exit upon receiving invalid input?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program where it converts imperial to metric. The part I am having trouble with is that with any input that is an invalid number (any negative) I am supposed to terminate the program without using exit, break, or system exit.

```
print('Hello, Please input the Imperial values!')
#Miles
Miles = float(input('Miles to Kilometers: '))
totalKilometers = (1.6 * Miles)
if Miles < 0:
 print('Please no negative numbers')
else:
 if Miles > 0:
    print("The metric conversion is ", totalKilometers)
#Fahrenheit
Fahrenheit = float(input('Fahrenheit to Celsius: '))
totalCelcius = ((Fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9 )
if Fahrenheit < 0 or Fahrenheit > 1000:
print('Please check your Fahrenheit number, It must be greater than 0 and
less than 1000')
else:
 if Fahrenheit > 0 or Fahrenheit < 1000:
   print("The metric conversion is ", totalCelcius)
#Gallons
Gallons = float(input('Gallons to Liters: '))
totalLiters = (3.9 * Gallons)
 if Gallons < 0:
print('Please no negative numbers')
else:
 if Gallons > 0:
    print("The metric conversion is ", totalLiters)
#Pounds
Pounds = float(input('Pounds to Kilograms: '))
totalKilograms = (.45 * Pounds)
if Pounds < 0:
print('Please no negative numbers')
else:
 if Pounds > 0:
  print("The metric conversion is ", totalKilograms)
#Inches
Inches = float(input('Inches to Cenitmeters: '))
totalCentimeters = (2.54 * Inches)
 if Inches < 0:
print('Please no negative numbers')
else:
 if Inches > 0:
    print("The metric conversion is ", totalCentimeters)
```

Comment: you can't use `exit`? why?

Comment: Sounds like you are supposed to raise an exception.

Comment: Other ways to exit a program including falling off the end of the main script (so, e.g., put this whole thing in a function, make a call to that function the only other top-level code, then `return` from that function, and you'll exit), `raise SystemExit()`, raising a normal exception (and not handling it), various functions that effectively just call `sys.exit` under the covers, using `ctypes` to exit the process at the C level out from under the interpreter…

Comment: Your code is not formatted, and there is too much of it for this question.

Comment: Anyway, your code already exits with an unhandled exception if the user answers, say, `spam`, so… is that what it's supposed to do? If so, it's probably supposed to do something similar if the user enters `-10`. But only you know that; we don't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't exit out of the program, define all of the code you already have as a function and use return. The code would look something like this:

```
def imp-met():
    print('Hello, Please input the Imperial values!')
    #Miles
    Miles = float(input('Miles to Kilometers: '))
    totalKilometers = (1.6 * Miles)
    if Miles < 0:
        print('Please no negative numbers')
        return
    (rest of code using return when needed)
imp-met()
```